# Data reshape in python

Tags: python, pivot

I have a sample data such as:

```
    User_ID        bucket          brand_name
0      100     3_6months             A
1     7543     6_9months             A
2      100    9_12months             A
3     7543     3_6months             B
4     7542  first_3months            C
```

Now I want to reshape this data to one row per userid such that my output data looks like:

```
User_ID A_first_3months  A_3_6months a6_9months A_last_9_12months B_3_6months B6_9month (so on)
 100     0              1          2                     1                
7543     2              0          1                     1
7542     0                         0          1           0
```

So here I basically want to pivot among two rows named, bucket and brand_name and aggregate it into one row per user. I know about pandas crosstabulate, pivot and stack functions. But not able to judge the right way as we have three columns.Any help would be highly appreciated. Here the entries can be more then one as we have are looking total count of brands in particular bucket for each user.

Comment: Your question is not in user friendly readable format ? try using some tools to highlight the relevant text and give proper spacing as well

Comment: @Anmol_uppal: Yeah I have edited it on the same go!!

Comment: @user2007506 Why do you have 2 for (100, a6_9months)?

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the brand and the bucket into a new column, and then apply crosstabs to it:

```
df['brand_bucket'] = df['brand_name'] + '_' + df['bucket']
pd.crosstab(index=[df['User_ID']], columns=[df['brand_bucket']])
```

yields

```
brand_bucket  A_3_6months  A_9_12months  B_3_6months  B_6_9months  \
User_ID                                                             
100                     1             1            0            0   
7542                    0             0            0            0   
7543                    0             0            1            1   

brand_bucket  C_last_3months  
User_ID                       
100                        0  
7542                       1  
7543                       0
```

Or, you could pass two columns to `crosstab` and obtain a DataFrame with a MultiIndex:

```
pd.crosstab(index=[df['User_ID']], columns=[df['bucket'], df['brand_name']])
```

yields

```
bucket     3_6months    6_9months 9_12months last_3months
brand_name         A  B         B          A            C
User_ID                                                  
100                1  0         0          1            0
7542               0  0         0          0            1
7543               0  1         1          0            0
```

I like the latter better because preserves more of the structure of the data.